# Best way to run node.js as a windows/mac service without node.js installed on target machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos

We do not want to require our clients to install node.js on their Mac or Windows machines.  We would like our clients to run an installer that would install a windows or mac service.   The service, when started, would start the node executable from the install directory (basically run ‘node server.js’ with node.exe included in the install) and then monitor that node application and restart it if the service dies.  (We are using window-node and windows-mac now but they require node.js to be installed first.)  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: have you found a way to do this?